# How can I import a global library to let use all of the components in my project in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using [angular2localization](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization) library. According to [quickstart guide](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization/blob/master/doc/quick-start.md) I have to add all of my components (which are using this library) these lines (import, extends Locale, consturctor arguments) to use this library

```
import { Locale, LocaleService, LocalizationService } from 'angular2localization';

export class ApplicationFormComponent extends Locale {
    constructor( public locale: LocaleService, public localization: LocalizationService ) {
        super(locale, localization);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add libraries like this more efficient way?

I wonder what is the standard and effective way to add a library to be used in all of the components.

Comment: That's the way it should be used.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what if I have to change some code in these lines? should I edit them in all of my components?

Comment: What change? I guess the answer is yes. Angular2 uses constructor injection (for good reasons) and constructors have some limitations. We have to live with it. Workarounds are possible but also have serious disadvantages.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am not experienced in ts and ag2 but I wonder what if I will have to use another library that must be used like that? Extending from 2 classes isn't supported in typescript. Probably I am asking silly questions but I am just trying to understand oop correctly. Sorry for that.

Comment: You can use a single `GlobalServices` service and inject that everywhere and then add a getter for another service to `GlobalService` to make an additional service available everywhere. I don't know what you would need inheritance for that.